# Tree Structure query in oracle , with one integer field and on varchar field

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, hierarchical-query

Here I need the tree structure query, with one int and other is varchar field. I don't want to modify varchar to int.

Table structure:

```
ID  INT
SUB_TASK_ID INT
TASK_ID INT
PID INT
WBS_ID  VARCHAR
WBS_TYPE VARCHAR
```

Here I'm trying to cast the wbs_id

```
SELECT * 
from art_sub_task_allocation 
START WITH sub_task_id IN (929) 
CONNECT BY PRIOR  CAST(wbs_id AS Numeric(10,0)) = sub_task_id;
```

But I get error :CONNECT BY loop in user data

Comment: What is your question? Are you getting an error, or wrong results? Please edit you question to show sample data, expected results, and what you get now.

Comment: What is the error/issue you are facing? Also show sample data.

Comment: Error :CONNECT BY loop in user data

Comment: My wbs_id is varchar so, tree structure query is not working, so I'm trying to cast wbs_id, it's not working with,  SELECT * from art_sub_task_allocation 
START WITH sub_task_id IN (929) CONNECT BY PRIOR  wbs_id = sub_task_id;  due to varchar

Comment: WHY do you not want to modify varchar to int? You think CONNECT BY loop has something to do with it? If the issue is the CONNECT BY loop, then ask a question about it, not about something else. CONNECT BY loop has absolutely nothing to do with casting varchar to int. Then: Use varchar2, not varchar, in Oracle. Use TO_NUMBER instead of CAST; and use NUMBER(10,0) instead of NUMERIC(10,0). And most importantly, if WBS_ID should be int, declare it so in the table creation! None of these, though, have anything to do with CONNECT BY loop.

Comment: The error message is telling you that your so-called "tree structure" is not a tree. There is a cycle in your table: there are rows with the following values for sub_task_id and wbs_id: (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1) (maybe not with the numbers 1, 2, 3 but with different numbers, and maybe a cycle longer than three steps). You could use NOCYCLE as suggested in an Answer; but if this is unexpected, it should be analyzed and if in fact it's in error, the error should be fixed first. Otherwise it's garbage in, garbage out.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use `NOCYCLE`.

```
SELECT *
      FROM art_sub_task_allocation
START WITH sub_task_id IN (929)
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR CAST (wbs_id AS NUMERIC (10, 0)) = sub_task_id;
```

You may also use `TO_NUMBER` instead of `CAST`.

```
PRIOR TO_NUMBER (wbs_id) = sub_task_id
```

Comment: Also note that you can use `CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE` as a column to see where the loop is in your data. http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_advanced_sql_connect_by_loop.htm

Answer (score 0):

When I see a table with columns called SUB_TASK_ID and TASK_ID I immediately think "compound key". That is I would presume that SUB_TASK_ID is only unique with TASK_ID. If that is the case you need to include TASK_ID in the CONNECT BY clause.

```
SELECT * 
from art_sub_task_allocation 
START WITH sub_task_id IN (929) 
CONNECT BY PRIOR  CAST(wbs_id AS Numeric(10,0)) = sub_task_id
      AND PRIOR TASK_ID = TASK_ID;
```